What is the basis explanation of the equation governing Maximum Recombination Rate?
According to the Shockley-Read-Hall (SRH) recombination model , Maximum recombination rate is mathematically represented as: $$U_\text{max} = \frac{1}{2} n_i\ v_{th}\ \sigma_0\ e^{V/2V_T} N_t ,$$ where $N_t$ is the trap density , $v_{th}$ is the thermal velocity, $\sigma_0$ is the capture cross-section, $V$ is the applied voltage, and $V_T$ is the thermal voltage. How it is derived ?
